# mysql sql qyery performace slow for 300k result retrieval

Tags: mysql

I have 300k data in my database.through ajax and php i am retrieving result from table. when i try to retrieve this data using below query then it is very slow.

is there any other way to write this query so that i get result very fast?

```
SELECT e_user_id,
       assembly_no,
       polling_station_number,
       polling_station_name_hindi,
       polling_station_name_eng,
       serial_number,
       section_no,
       section_name_hindi,
       section_name_eng,
       house_no,
       e_first_name_hindi,
       e_first_name_eng,
       e_last_name_eng,
       e_relation_type,
       e_relative_first_name_hindi,
       e_relative_last_name_hindi,
       e_relative_first_name_eng,
       e_relative_last_name_eng,
       id_card_number,
       gender,
       age,
       dob,
       contact_number,
       uid
FROM   vw_absent_record
WHERE  polling_station_number IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4,
                                   5, 6, 7, 8,
                                   9, 10, 11, 12,
                                   13, 14, 15, 16,
                                   17, 18, 19, 20,
                                   21, 22, 23, 24,
                                   25, 26, 27 )
       AND assembly_no = 48
ORDER  BY e_user_id ASC
```

this is the index query and e_voter_list table

```
CREATE view vw_absent_record
AS
  SELECT e_voter_list.e_user_id,
         e_voter_list.assembly_no,
         e_voter_list.polling_station_number,
         e_voter_list.polling_station_name_hindi,
         e_voter_list.polling_station_name_eng,
         e_voter_list.serial_number,
         e_voter_list.section_no,
         e_voter_list.section_name_hindi,
         e_voter_list.section_name_eng,
         e_voter_list.house_no,
         e_voter_list.e_first_name_hindi,
         e_voter_list.e_first_name_eng,
         e_voter_list.e_last_name_eng,
         e_voter_list.e_relation_type,
         e_voter_list.e_relative_first_name_hindi,
         e_voter_list.e_relative_last_name_hindi,
         e_voter_list.e_relative_first_name_eng,
         e_voter_list.e_relative_last_name_eng,
         e_voter_list.id_card_number,
         e_voter_list.gender,
         e_voter_list.age,
         e_voter_list.dob,
         e_voter_list.contact_number,
         e_voter_list.uid
  FROM   e_voter_list
         LEFT OUTER JOIN vw_attendance_record
                      ON
         ( e_voter_list.e_user_id = vw_attendance_record.e_user_id )
  WHERE  vw_attendance_record.e_user_id IS NULL
```

this is my e_voter_list table

```
 CREATE TABLE `e_voter_list` (
      `e_user_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
      `assembly_no` bigint(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `polling_station_number` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `polling_station_name_hindi` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
      `polling_station_name_eng` varchar(350) DEFAULT NULL,
      `serial_number` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `section_no` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `section_name_hindi` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
      `section_name_eng` varchar(450) DEFAULT NULL,
      `house_no` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_first_name_hindi` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_last_name_hindi` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_first_name_eng` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_last_name_eng` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_relation_type` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_relative_first_name_hindi` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_relative_last_name_hindi` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_relative_first_name_eng` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `e_relative_last_name_eng` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
      `id_card_number` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `gender` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
      `age` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `dob` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
      `contact_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
      `uid` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
      `status_type` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `year_of_birth` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
      `date_of_attendance` date DEFAULT NULL,
      `attendance_status` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `e_attendance_timestamp` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `update_agent_id` int(7) DEFAULT NULL,
      `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Did you create any indexs?

Comment: Is the query running slow or the data transfer too slow?

Comment: Could you please post create table for **vw_absent_record** ?

Comment: yes i created index.

Comment: please see the index query i have edited

Comment: Could you please add complete tables which you use in your queries ? Please add formatted data

Comment: You have not defined any index on **e_voter_list** and because of that your select query from view become slow. first you need to define proper indexes on **e_voter_list** and **vw_attendance_record** table. could you please post structure of **vw_attendance_record** too ?

Comment: Please don't use Indian words like 'lac' here.

Comment: why cant i use Indian words??please give me a valid reason

Answer (score 0):

Have you used indexing in your table? If not then please implement indexing on columns then your select query will be fast. Also I will suggest you to get records by using limit and offset like this:

```
    SELECT e_user_id,assembly_no,polling_station_number,polling_station_name_hindi,polling_station_name_eng,serial_number,section_no,section_name_hindi,section_name_eng,house_no,e_first_name_hindi,e_first_name_eng,e_last_name_eng,e_relation_type,e_relative_first_name_hindi,e_relative_last_name_hindi,e_relative_first_name_eng,e_relative_last_name_eng,id_card_number,gender,age,dob,contact_number,uid FROM vw_absent_record where polling_station_number IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27) and assembly_no=48 ORDER BY e_user_id ASC LIMIT 10,0
```

Comment: if i set LIMIT then how to retrieve all the data on single click?

Comment: If you get all data then you will definitely face some issues as data grows. Your pc might hang or you will face an error of execution time out etc. Try to get data in bundles like pagination works.